# unable to load solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr, drupal-7, tomcat6

I am using Apache Solr on my drupal website.
Tomcat 6 is installed and I have replaced schema.xml, solr-config.xml and protwords.txt files with the new files which was present in module installation directory.

When I run localhost:8983, I get this error.

```
Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)

2528 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Failed to load file /opt/solr-4.5.1/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml

2529 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Unable to create core: egitraining-dev.esc.rl.ac.uk
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /opt/solr-4.5.1/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:490)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:557)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:247)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:239)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/conf/', cwd=/opt/solr-4.5.1/example
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:287)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:487)
        ... 11 more

2531 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: egitraining-dev.esc.rl.ac.uk
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:934)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:566)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:247)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:239)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /opt/solr-4.5.1/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:490)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:557)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/conf/', cwd=/opt/solr-4.5.1/example
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:287)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:487)
        ... 11 more


2533 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – user.dir=/opt/solr-4.5.1/example

2533 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init() done

2576 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  – Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

Can anyone help Please?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This might have something to do with the default Solr config files provided by the Search API Solr module. Try to remove the next couple of lines from solrconfig.xml:

```
<useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
<ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
<mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>
```

Patch found at https://drupal.org/comment/7945999#comment-7945999.